# What're the best references for TEX macros?

Tags: macros

I need to learn about the famous TEX macros. if there are good references. but for beginners -step by step-

Not limited to. :: `\foo` `\par` `\@@par`

And commands to create the macros:: `\def`, `\newcommand`, `\renewcommand`, `\newenvironment`,  `\let`

Comment: Have you checked the basic learning resources here: [What are good learning resources for a LaTeX beginner?](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/11) and  [Where do I start LaTeX programming?](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/12668)

Comment: @AlanMunn, yes.surely

Comment: I'm not sure what your response means. Basically your question is a duplicate of one of these two questions. And since you're asking about the definition of `\foo` (which is the prototypical example of a name used purely for example code, and not a "real" macro) you may want to work with the sources in the first question first.

Comment: your question isn't clear, the site works best if you just ask one focussed question. Your first part is not really answerable, `\foo` is not defined by default, it is possibly just used as an example name in some example you saw. `\par` is not a macro it is the tex primitove to end a paragraph and `\@@par` is a latex name for a saved version of `\par`.  The question about how to use `\newcommand` is surely a duplicate.

Comment: for hints on defining macros see for example https://www.learnlatex.org/en/lesson-06#defining-commands

Comment: https://www.math.uh.edu/~torok/math_6298/latex/